# How do i add multiple worksheets and name them with cell references?

Tags: excel, vba, addition

I am creating a macro in my PERSONAL.xlsb workbook so that it can be used across all my workbooks.

The macro takes information from workbook 1, copies it into workbook 2, and then takes new information from workbook 2 and puts it into the new worksheets i create in workbook 1.

I am stuck at the part where i want to add multiple sheets to my workbook.

I thought this was simple but i have tried a number of ways to add sheets to my workbook but i keep receiving errors. I tried to create a simple macro that only added sheets but i kept receiving errors for this one line of code.

What do i need to do in order to add worksheets to my workbook?

' Attempt 1: Doesn't work - Run-Time error 1004
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:="Sheet23"

' Attempt 2: Doesn't work - Run-Time error 1004
Sheets.Add After:="Sheet23"

'Attempt 3: Doesn't work - Run-Time error 1004
Sheets.Add After:=Sheet23

'Attempt 4: Doesn't work - Run-Time error 1004
Worksheets.Add after:=Sheet23

Desired output (basic): I want to add a new worksheet after sheet 23 in my workbook

Desired output (ideal): I want to add a number of worksheets after sheet 23 according to the number of entries that i have in my list. Each item in the list is numbered from 1 onwards. Each new worksheet should be named according to this number.

Comment: It's looking for a sheet index, or the object itself. Try `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet23")`

Comment: Hi Chris, please update your question to produce a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help diagnose the issue a little better! (it could be caused by something other than where the error is thrown). Also there are limits (by memory) to the number of worksheets you can have in excel which could be causing your issues... [see here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). Have you tried manually adding the sheets or just the sheets after 23?

Comment: If you need to add them at the end of the workbook, assuming `wb` is the reference for the workbook: `wb.Sheets.add after.=wb.sheets(wb.sheets.count)` This code will always add the sheet to the end of your workbook.

Answer (score 0):

The after argument wants a worksheet object not a string so you need

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.add after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet23")
```

But you can also use the index number so

```
 Dim i as integer
 i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet23").Index
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add after:= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
```

If we assume that your list is in (for the sake of argument) sheet1.range("a1") downwards then we could write

```
  Sub MakeSheetsFromList()
  Dim r As Range
  Set r = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
  Dim i As Integer
  i = Worksheets("sheet23").Index
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Do
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(i))
    ws.Name = r.Text
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
    i = i + 1
 Loop Until r = ""
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The first one gives me a Run-Time 9 error.

Comment: Is there an issue because I'm adding the macro to my PERSONAL.xlsb? Is there something more basic that I haven't done because it seems so strange that one of the most basic lines of code in VBA isn't working

Comment: We are assuming that there is a sheet23 in the activeworkbook . In the vast majority of cases there won't be, so I'm not sure why you would want this to be universally available. That said, what is teh value of i when you get the error?